# How to use a single form between two ui:define

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, facelets, composite-component

I've got a simple template where is defined two areas, toolbar and content. The toolbar area has the many commandButtons and the content has fields.
My problem is: How to use a single form between two ui:define?

I've the sample code:

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="toolbar">
        <p:commandButton id="saveButton" value="Save" ajax="false" action="#{...}" />
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="registerForm">
            <p:outputLabel for="name" value="Name"/>
            <p:inputText id="name" value="#{...}" required="true" />
            <p:message for="name"/>
         </h:form>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

When de saveButton is trigger, the h:form registerForm should be submitted.

Anybody have a suggestion?

Comment: the reason to use one form is because when commandButton is clicked the values of <p:inputText id="name" value="#{...}" required="true" /> is not submitted and my action throws a NullPointerException.
PS: i don't want use ajax to submit values.

Comment: Is there a reason to use just one form?

Comment: No, if you has a sugestion to solve this problem with two forms, please, tell me.
The only requisit is: have a two areas in template and don't use ajax to submit the content form. You can help me?

Comment: Without Ajax 2 forms is no go. If you want to use this in one form you need to place your <h:form> tags your in your template. Drawback of this approach is that you can't use the form tags anymore in your pages because then you get nested forms and thats not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with ui:decorator. Using ui:decorator like a "subtemplate" is possible put the form between many ui:define.
I hope this can help.

**template-decorate.xhml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <ui:define name="toolbar"></ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content"></ui:define>
</html>
```

**register.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"

    <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form id="registerForm">
                <ui:decorate template="/WEB-INF/templates/layout-decorator.xhtml">

                    <ui:define name="toolbar">
                        <p:commandButton id="saveButton" value="Save" ajax="false" action="#{...}" />
                    </ui:define>

                    <ui:define name="form">
                        <p:outputLabel for="name" value="Name"/>
                        <p:inputText id="name" value="#{...}" required="true" />
                        <p:message for="name"/>
                    </ui:define>
                </ui:decorate>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

For more information see: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ui/decorate.html